# How do programs like CPU-Z / HWMonitor monitor?

Tags: monitoring, cpu

So this has been something that has been bugging me for a while.
How do programs such as CPU-Z actually monitor things such as voltage and frequency? I am by no means a very experienced programmer, but things that seem complicated always interest me.
Things that I have used, WMI for example, seem to provide a snapshot, and are inaccurate. CPU frequency doesn't change, and voltage is rounded to two digits (e.g. anything from 1.1 to 1.199 becomes 1.1).
I would expect that some sort of driver has been written, to grant lower-level access, but Googling seems to reveal nothing on how these programs work.
If anyone could enlighten me, and possible give a code example (if it is not too difficult), I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely some very low level programming against either the BIOS or the Chipset.  You'd probably have to find documentation on Intels or AMDs website to do something similar.

Comment: HWmonitor accesses a driver called "cpuz" the documentation to this driver is contained in their commercial SDK https://www.cpuid-pro.com/licenses-pricing.php
Even searching closely in device manager I couldn't find it 
But it is interacted with calls like CreateFileA ( "\\.\cpuz155", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL ) 0x0000000000000394  0.0000224

Answer (score 1):

the voltage can be read with RDMSR instruction（index 0x198），you can check the 64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual for details.you may need the library winring0, visual studio doesn't support RDMSR instruction.you can google winring0 to download the library.the core voltage=EBX[bit0-bit15]*(float)1/(2^12).
I tried but haven't got the right frequency yet.
[64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual](http://www.intel.cn/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)